# Angular logs incorrect url on detail page

Tags: angular, url, caching, parameters

I have a simple service responsible for fetching movies from an open API. I can succsefully display the movie, poster, title, etc, but when I navigate to the detail page Angular assumes a wrong url containing a users middleware. 
THese are the main routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuardService]},
  {path:'', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'detail/:id', component:DetailComponent},
  {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
];
```

The service:

```
getMovies(name: string, year?: string, season?: string) {

    return this.http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='
      + name + '&plot=short&y=' + year + '&apikey=87c31e60');
  }
```

The link for detail:

```
<h5 class="card-title"><a [routerLink]="['/detail', m.Title]">{{m.Title}}, {{m.Year}}</a></h5>
```

And the detail component:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.route.paramMap.pipe(switchMap(params => {
      let id = params.get('id');
      return this.movieService.getMovies(id);
    })).subscribe(movie => { 
      this.movie = movie 
    console.log(movie)}); 
  }
```

The log on the init method shows something like:

`:4200/users/Mad%20Max:%20Fury%20Road:1 Failed to load resource: the server`

So it "writes" the path for users and I dont understand why. This app uses a fakebackend and has an array of users in that file, but all those services are disabled and i'm trying only to work with this one. It uses cache, of course, but I tried to build this system on a clean app and it works, though the cache still exists...can some one help me out?

EDIT:

This is the userService but only triggered by the admin module...

```
getAll() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`/users`);
  }

  getUser(id: number | string) {
    return this.http.get(`/users/${id}`);
  }

  deleteUser(id: number | string) {
    return this.http.delete(`/users/${id}`);
  }
```

Comment: this `{path:'', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch:'full'},` has to be your last route configured. It cannot be in the middle

Comment: I've changed the order but the users path remains and I get the error...

Comment: I do not see any `/users/` route configured. Where or how is it triggered?

Comment: well, that's the problem, i don't know, maybe i should post more code

Comment: ok I think i see the problem, I have a detail user page with the same token id. Can that be it?

Comment: its solved, I had two routes with the same name...Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I had two routes with the same name:

```
export const routes: Routes = [

  {path:'detail/:id', component:UserDetailComponent},---->

];
```

And

```
{path:'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuardService]},
  {path:'detail/:id', component:DetailComponent}, ----> Same name
  {path:'', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch:'full'}

];
```

Changed to:

```
  {path:'movieDetail/:title', component:DetailComponent}
```